# Are preemptive servers safe to use in a multiregion autoscaler?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Say I have a webserver, and use 1 server that's non pre-emptive in one region, and then many single servers that are pre-emptive in other regions in a Global autoscaler.

If a preemptive server shuts down, will that region automatically be unavailable, or would I have to manually remove the region from the autoscaler from a shutdown script?

Comment: did I answer your question? if so, please accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto scaling in GCP is based on managed instance groups which are created from templates, so they are either preemptible or not. In case of preemptible instances, the group manager keeps the number of live instances when some are stopped. Managed instance groups are either regional or zonal.

If you want to have a global service, you can run multiple managed instance groups in multiple regions and a global backend service.

As for your question, if some of your managed instance groups consist of preemptible instances and some are shut down, the group manager will take care of that and replace the instances. the region may be unavailable for a short period of time and load balancer health checks should detect that and not send traffic to unhealthy instances.

Personally, I wouldn't use preemptible instances for workloads that are under SLAs.

Comment: I mainly wanted to know if it's safe to use preemptive servers in global autoscaling regions as long as there's one region with non preemptive. Do you know?